# when i use antd,there are some error in terminal

Tags: reactjs, antd

'@ant-design/icons' does not contain an export named 'LoadingOutlined'.    in browser

"export 'LoadingOutlined' was not found in '@ant-design/icons'   in terminal

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide as much information as possible (code examples and such) so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

1. npm install --save @ant-design/icons
2. `import { LoadingOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons"`
3. To use the icon in your component do this `<LoadingOutlined />`